# Finding the Penultimate Element in Scala List

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I was learning about pattern matching on collections to write a simple logic generically to find the last but one element. Here is my first attempt:

```
@scala.concurrent.tailrec
def penultimate[A](elems: List[A]) = elems match {
  case Nil => None 
  case first :: second :: Nil => Some(first)
  case head :: tail => penultimate(tail)
}
```

Is this good enough? I read about tail recursions and I made my method a tail recursive one!

However, it fails for the following case and where I expect Some(1):

```
penultimate[Int](List(1)) // This should give me Some(1)
```

Is there anything better that I could do? I can use the reverse method from the Scala collections library and make this a one liner, but I wanted to stay away from using it.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: What you're saying is not correct. First: your code does not compile. Second: when you fix the compilation errors `penultimate(List(1))` returns `None`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! I have edited my post!

Comment: Now I am confused. Why would you _expect_ `Some(1)`?

Comment: If the List just contains one element, I would like to return that element! This is just some experimentation for me. Not a hard and fast rule to do what when there is only one element in the List. I liked you answer which is very concise and short, but for someone like me beginning with Scala, it might be not so straight forward to understand the usage of wildcards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your code seems to work correctly if you fix those 2 simple compilation errors.</s> An alternative way to write this method is:

```
def penultimate[A](elems: List[A]) = elems match {
  case _ :+ elem :+ _ => Some(elem)
  case elem +: Nil => Some(elem) // strange extra requirement
  case _ => None
}
```

`:+` deconstructs a `Seq` into (1) a list of all but the last element, and (2) the last element. Like `::` or the more general `+:` but backwards. I could have written `case init :+ elem :+ last`, but I prefer not to give names to the parts of the pattern I don't intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of Penultimate in the first place is that you should have at least 2 elements in the list. So in above "penultimateInt" should throw exception.

```
def penultimate[A](elems: List[A]) = {
  val result = getSecondLast(elems)
  if(result.isDefined) result.get else throw new Exception("list doesn't have 
    enough elementss")
}

@tailrec
private def getSecondLast[A](list: List[A], secondLast: Option[A] = None): 
  Option[A] = {
  list match {
    case secondLast :: _ :: Nil => Some(secondLast)
    case _ :: tail => getSecondLast(tail, secondLast)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Above is the recursive approach.
Other ways using the available methods are:

1. list.init.last
2. list.takeRight(n).head